# Running multiple commands in cmd via psexec

Tags: ant, cmd, configuration-management, psexec

I'm working on creating a single command that will run mulitple things on the command line of another machine. Here is what I'm looking to do.

- Use psexec to access remote machine
- travel to proper directory and file
- execute ant task
- exit cmd
- run together in one line

I can run the below command from Run to complete what I need accomplished but can't seem to get the format correct for psexec to understand it.

```
cmd /K cd /d D:\directory & ant & exit
```

I've tried appling this to the psexec example below:

```
psexec \\machine cmd /K cd /d D:\directory & ant & exit
```

When executing this it will activate the command line and travel to `D:\directory` but won't execute the remaining commands.  Adding `""` just creates more issues.

Can anyone guide me to the correct format? Or something other than psexec I can use to complete this (free options only)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Figured it out finally after some more internet searching and trial and error.  psexec needs /c to run multiple commands, but that syntax doesn't work with the setup I wrote above.  I've gotten the below command to run what I need.

```
psexec \\machine cmd /c (^d:^ ^& cd directory^ ^& ant^)
```

I don't need to exit because psexec will exit itself upon completion.  You can also use && to require success to continue on to the next command.  Found this forum helpful

[http://forum.sysinternals.com/psexec_topic318.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20161018222251/http://forum.sysinternals.com/psexec_topic318.html)

And this for running psexec commands

http://ss64.com/nt/psexec.html

Comment: Can you please explain to me when exactly to put `^`, I can't figure it out with this code.

Answer (score 2):

This works:

psexec \ComputerName cmd /c "echo hey1 & echo hey2"

Answer (score 1):

For simple cases I use:

```
PsExec \\machine <options> CMD /C "command_1 & command_2 & ... & command_N"
```

For more complex cases, using a batch file with [PsExec's `-c` switch](https://www.itprotoday.com/compute-engines/psexec) may be more suitable:

> *The -c switch directs PsExec to copy the specified executable to the remote system for execution and delete the executable from the remote system when the program has finished running.*

```
PsExec \\machine <options> -c PSEXEC_COMMANDS.cmd <arguments>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked about other options and this has tag configuration managment-- I guess you may be interested in [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) (or Hudson). It provide very good way of creating master-slave mechanism which may help in simplifying the build process.

Answer (score 0):

I always use like this way :) and works properly

```
psexec \\COMPUTER -e cmd /c (COMMAND1 ^& COMMAND2 ^& COMMAND3)
```